# How to install steam on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, steam

I have installed Steam on my Linux, followed the instruction to download lib32, but after doing that, my Linux  just crashed. It was not booting in normal mode (just recovery mode), lost all my data (nothing much to worry about). Now I did reinstall Linux on my laptop again. Is there any safe way to install Steam without crushing system, it says missing lib32 and I can't do same operations iIdid (`apt install libc6:i386`), it just not gonna work! I could not find any solution on the internet rather than downloading lib32!

Comment: What kind of "linux" you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS

Comment: You can install steam by `sudo apt install steam`. I do it this way and all works.

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
this is message i get in terminal

Comment: It means you did something wrong before.

Comment: i just reinstalled ubunto and first thing  i did was to ask here have not touched terminal since installation

Comment: This can't be. You can't have broken packages after a fresh install.

Comment: it is what it is can not understand why i get this message i did only install live package as ubuntu was aking

Comment: What is "live package"?

Comment: it said was the update

Comment: If an update crashed, that can be a reason.

Comment: no it did not crashed it executed just fine

Comment: something must've gone wrong during install, this isn't normal at all. maybe run `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
these are final two lines

Answer (score 4):

You can install with this code in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Or with GUI browser:
Go to this link and download .deb file: https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/client/installer/steam.deb
Click to .deb file for starting installing package.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install steam
```

thats the command you should have written.